# Trying to login into webpage with cookies and requests

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to log in into a website called [www.zalando.fr](http://www.zalando.fr) with requests in python (i don't want to use selenium) I tried to send a post request with my login credentials, but I didn't find out which request do i have to send (i am not very experienced with requests and any of the post requests seems like having my credentials) and i heard that you can login by using the same cookies as the ones in your already started session, so i tried the following:

```
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
from requests import Session
from requests.utils import cookiejar_from_dict
from codecs import open



def main():
    cookies = '''plain text cookies i got by doing document.cookie after logging in'''
    s = Session()
    cookie_dict = {}
    for cookie in cookies.split(";"):
       cookie =  cookie.split("=")
       cookie_dict[cookie[0]] = cookie[1]
    cj = cookiejar_from_dict(cookie_dict)
    print("Cookie jar to dict done...")
    s.cookies = cj
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }
    print("Requesting")
    html = s.get("https://www.zalando.fr/myaccount/", headers=headers)
    print("request done")

    html = s.get("https://www.zalando.fr/myaccount/", headers=headers)
    print("request done")
    if "My name" in html.text:
        print('Good')
    else:
        print("Bad")
    with open("response.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html.text) 
    s.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The if at the end checks if my name is in the page, because there is a message that says "Bonjour User" when you log in, but it always seems like it is not logged in.
and when i open response.html it shows the login page, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not directly visible to client-side programs such as JavaScript if they have been sent with the HttpOnly flag. So with `document.cookie` you are not getting any authentication cookies.

Go developer tools under `Application` -> `Storage` -> `Cookies` you will find all the cookies.